# Windows 8.1 dreamspark version can be upgraded to Windows 10 for free?

Tags: windows, dreamspark

I have a Windows 8.1 computer with a Dreamspark license, can my computer be upgraded to W10 for free?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## Yes.

DreamSpark versions of Windows are identical to retail versions, the only difference is how they are licensed: You can use them only in virtual machines and on computers for which you have a retail/OEM Windows license.

For example my laptop came with Windows 7 preinstalled, so I could replace it with Windows 8.1 from DreamSpark. I also have an older computer for which I have bought Vista, so I could upgrade it to Windows 8 (and get free upgrade to Windows 8.1).

DreamSpark versions of Windows 8.1 are already offering Windows 10 upgrade reservation, look for the Windows logo icon in notification area to opt in:

[image: Screenshot of GWX window and icon]

Note that you can get four copies of Windows 10 from DreamSpark:

- You are eligible for one for free once it's released
- You can upgrade Windows 8.1 to Windows 10
- Same with Windows 7 which also gets a free upgrade
- You can upgrade Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 and then to Windows 10